# File specified cannot be found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I have been programming in C++ for quite a while and, having game-creation experience in other languages(e.g. Javascript) I decided it was time to take the leap into games.

After trawling through the internet I decided that 32-bit SFML(2.3.1) for Visual C++ 12 (Visual Studio 2013) was the best option for me. I have before tried SFML and other libraries(like Allegro) but before I had *really* understood C++ and VS. I have set it up *exactly* as it said [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-vc.php). I did that **twice** with two projects. I added the code from that project (copy and paste both times). This is the *exact* code copied from **my** project so you can tell if there's any errors in **my** code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
     {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My file location is this:

> C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\sfml_test

When I try to compile this program I get this error:

> Unable to start program 'c:\users\daniel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\sfml_test\Debug\sfml_test.exe'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

I checked the file and it showed no exe file.

Comment: btw, just test and see if it works in release mode instead of debug and also try to include #include "stdafx.h" and see if it works

Comment: I assume you would get a message like that if compilation failed due to errors, but I'm not sure if that would be the issue here.

Comment: Make sure you add the source file to the project itself (see [here](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=18568.0) for a similar sounding issue).

Comment: Did you actually compile it? That response is usually shown when trying to debug, and if you didnt' compile beforehand, the file of course won't be there